# I need to save a booking id returning from an external api in meta data field but add action do action and filter where to place these to call please

Tags: filter, action, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a function with filter but i dont know what to pass add_filter what i read it needs 4 arguments is there anything fixed to pass this function please help

Please help i am super confused with all 4 parameters to pass in document examples i go the following code

```
function wpgetapi_save_customer_id( $result, $data, $values_sent, $endpoint ) {
    
    if( isset( $result['customer_id'] ) ) {

        $user_id = $data['data']['ID'];
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'crm_customer_id', $result['customer_id'] );
        
    }

}
add_filter( 'wpgetapi_after_user_register', 'wpgetapi_save_customer_id', 10, 4 );
```

i really dont know why are they passing 10 here as the values are not 10 here they are all
is this fixed number or what